# How to check public bool of different script in C# - Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, movement

I seem to have some trouble with a problem that I feel should be really simple, but I've been beating my head against this for a few hours and I can't seem to figure out what the hurtle is. What I'm trying to do is stop the player from moving when dialogue is running, the dialogue being run through a plugin called YarnSpinner. I have a public bool that I used to track this, named "StopTheWalking", and that seems to track just fine in the script. The problem is I've tried multiple different ways to call this bool from my 2D player movement script so that I can stop the player from moving when "StopTheWalking" is true, but I can't seem to get the movement script to register this. Also, the the two scripts aren't attached to the same GameObject. I'm still learning Unity myself, though I feel given the vast amounts of answers I've seen about this, (and I apologize for adding onto that list) but I just can't seem to find what the problem is. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

*EDIT*: I changed the script to include a reference to the "StopTheWalking" variable, and I called another public bool, "SeeIfTalking", to tick true if "StopTheWalking" is also true through FixedUpdate. I just wanted to test to see if this even registered, which is my main goal. Apologies again for the previous confusion!

Here's the movement script:

````
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Yarn.Unity;

namespace UnityStandardAssets._2D
{
    public class PlatformerCharacter2D : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private float m_MaxSpeed = 10f;                    // The fastest the player can travel in the x axis.
        [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 400f;                  // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
        [Range(0, 3)] [SerializeField] private float m_CrouchSpeed = .36f;  // Amount of maxSpeed applied to crouching movement. 1 = 100%
        [SerializeField] private bool m_AirControl = false;                 // Whether or not a player can steer while jumping;
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;                  // A mask determining what is ground to the character

        public Transform m_GroundCheck;    // A position marking where to check if the player is grounded.
        const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded
        private bool m_Grounded;            // Whether or not the player is grounded.
        public Transform m_CeilingCheck;   // A position marking where to check for ceilings
        const float k_CeilingRadius = .01f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if the player can stand up
        private Animator m_Anim;            // Reference to the player's animator component.
        private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;
        private bool m_FacingRight = true;  // For determining which way the player is currently facing.

        public bool m_SeeIfTalking;


        private void Awake()
        {

            m_GroundCheck = transform.Find("GroundCheck");
            m_CeilingCheck = transform.Find("CeilingCheck");
            m_Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
            m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            m_Grounded = false;

            Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
            for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                    m_Grounded = true;
            }
            m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", m_Grounded);

            // Set the vertical animation
            m_Anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

            if (GameObject.Find ("DialogueRunner").GetComponent<DialogueRunner> ().StopTheWalking == true) {

                m_SeeIfTalking = true;

            }
            else {
                m_SeeIfTalking = false;
            }
        }


        public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
        {
            // If crouch, check to see if the character can stand up
            if (!crouch && m_Anim.GetBool("Crouch"))
            {
                // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
                if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
                {
                    crouch = true;
                }
            }

            // Set whether or not the character is crouching in the animator
            m_Anim.SetBool("Crouch", crouch);

            //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
            if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
            {
                // Reduce the speed if crouching by the crouchSpeed multiplier
                move = (crouch ? move*m_CrouchSpeed : move);


                // The Speed animator parameter is set to the absolute value of the horizontal input.
                m_Anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

                // Move the character
                m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move*m_MaxSpeed, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

                // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
                if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
                {
                    // ... flip the player.
                    Flip();
                }
                    // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
                else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
                {
                    // ... flip the player.
                    Flip();
                }
            }

            if (m_Grounded && jump && m_Anim.GetBool("Ground"))
            {

                m_Grounded = false;
                m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
                m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
            }
        }


        private void Flip()
        {

            m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;


            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }
    }
}

```
````

Comment: I don't see a single attempt to reference this StopTheWalking variable anywhere in the code you've shared. So it's hard for us to understand how you've tried applying your research from [existing Q&A on this topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=Unity+another+script), so that we can narrow down precisely why the existing advice isn't working for you. Please edit your question to walk us through how you've tried to solve this based on your research, and where specifically you're running into trouble applying one of these documented solutions.

Comment: My apologies, I figured I would remove any attempts I made to start at square-one, but I can see why that wouldn't help in this case. I'll make an edit to the original post

Comment: Thanks for your edit. We're still missing some info though: what do you observe when you run this code? Does See If Talking change values? Do you see an error in your console indicating that one of the steps in finding DialogueRunner returned null? If you set a breakpoint and step through this method with the debugger, what do you get at each step of the expression in your if condition?

Comment: Just figured it out. Instead of trying to call the bool remotely, I instead added the GameObject the script was attached to publically to the 2D movement script, and now things seem to be working. It was odd considering despite it not working before, there were no errors both in the script or in the console, and the variable SeeIfTalking just remained false. Regardless, I appreciate you helping me!